# how to find the /dev/usb file is associated to a given vendor:product code

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

Is there a programmatic way to determine which of the files `/dev/usb/hiddev[0-9]` is associated to a given USB peripheral, given the `vendor:product` code of the USB peripheral (which I can get from using `lsusb`)?

That is, I want a command `which-usb-file` that works like this:

```
which-usb-file 0123:4567  -->  /dev/usb/hiddev3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following:

```
dmesg | grep 0123:4567 | tail -n 1 | sed -e "s/.*\(hiddev[0-9]\).*/\1/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
 udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/usb/hiddevX
```

This will output enough info to allow you to identify the device, including the Vendor identity and Code.

Comment: Many thanks, but I want to do the opposite: given the `vendor:product` to get the corresponding `hiddev`.  See my answer above for code I ended up using.